# Reference to proper instance of object volatile variable

Tags: java, multithreading

How `ClassThread` can access to `variable var` from instance of `Class1` that created this `ClassThread` instance?

**ClassThread**

```
public class ClassThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}
```

**Class1**

```
public class Class1 implements Runnable{

    public volatile String var;

    public Class1() {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            ClassThread ct = new ClassThread();
            Thread t = new Thread(ct);
            t.start();
        }
    }

}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            Class1 cla = new Class1();
            Thread t = new Thread(cla);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it as an argument in the constructor:

```
public class ClassThread implements Runnable {
    private volatile String var;

    public ClassThread(String var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}
```

And in `Class1`, pass it in when you construct the `ClassThread`:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        ClassThread ct = new ClassThread(var);
        Thread t = new Thread(ct);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: And then changes to passed volatile variable will be visible to another threads?

Comment: String is immutable, you can't change it. If it were a List, or an Array, then yes, you could change the contents in one thread and then other threads would see the changes. BUT there is potential for race conditions and lost updates, make sure you understand synchronization before changing a variable from multiple threads.